# Data for one column only displaying one date

Tags: sql, visual-studio, powerbi, dax, sql-server-data-tools

I have a question about modeling in Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools.  I am currently building a model where I have a fact table that is linked to a Date Dimension table using a Many : One relationship, in that order.  The Dimension table has a unique value (PK) that links to the fact table, where the Date is the Foreign Key.  For the sales table, there are many sales that happen on the same day.  Hence 1:M.
There is no code for this question.  However, when I go to refresh the table and bring them into my model, I am noticing that only ONE date shows up in a table for the Date column for the Dimension table.  In other words, all dates and transactions show up from the Fact table dataset.  However, for the Dimension table, only ONE date shows up:  11/1/2016.  I need them all to show up and be linked to the fact table.  If you are thinking that I might have the Date table filtered-- I have already checked this.  There are NO current and active filters on Date in the Date Dimension table.  I am puzzled as to why this is happening. 
Also, the data types between tables appear to be consistent.  Both are currently set to 'Short Date.'  Changing the date type, for both columns, to MM/DD/yyyy does nothing to solve the problem, either.

Comment: By your definition, the date is the PK, the date dimension should only ever have one record per date. Unless I do not understand the question.

Comment: the Date dimension table's PK does have only ONE (single) row per value, as a PK should.  When I bring in that PK into a table in Power BI and look at the values in it, alongside the Foreign Key in the fact Sales table, only 11/1/2016 aligns with the value.  As soon as the date changes in the fact table to 11/3/2016, there is no more linking between the PK and FK.

Comment: I think that there is some kind of problem with the modeling and the relationships, but I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: Are your date formats the same in the tables I see you are using MMDDYYYY. look at the table definitions. I am not a power BI expert so I am not sure but I would also check how you are joining the tables.Are you doing that in Power BI or in the database. What database are you using.

Comment: Hi Joe.  Thanks for trying to help.  Yes, I already checked that as well.  I can go back and double check.  I am using a SQL database.  As I look at both columns, Data Format is Short Date.  And Data Type is Date.  The same can be said for both the Date dim table and the fact Sales table.  Strange, right???

Comment: I am joining the tables through a create relationship interface in Visual Studio.  VS is not objecting to the join.

Comment: You are out of my area of knowledge now. If I were you I would add tags for Power BI and visual studio and the database you are using.

Comment: What is the range of dates you have in you date dimension? And what is the range of dates in your Sales table? Please edit your post and change PK for the Sales table into FK. The Date column in your Sales table is a Foreign Key, right?